# PagerSnapHelper with RecyclerView on Android Wear

Tags: android, android-recyclerview

I want to implement vertical scroll pages.

In the documentation for the [GridPagerAdapter](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/wearable/view/GridPagerAdapter.html) it is mentioned that it is deprecated and as a replacement the developer should use RecyclerView with PagerSnapHelper.

SnapHelper was introduced in version 24 of the RecyclerView library, and PagerSnapHelper in version 25.

Unfortunately the com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0 dependency only includes recyclerview-v7:23.0.1

Is there a way to fix this somehow?

Comment: Copy paste the class for now?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If this issue is still relevant, you can fix it, for example, in your build.gradle:

```
compile ('com.google.android.support:wearable:2.0.0') {
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'percent'
        exclude group: 'com.android.support', module: 'recyclerview-v7'
    }
compile 'com.android.support:recyclerview-v7:25.3.1'
```